# How can I visually inspect the real-time Activity and Fragment stack in an Android application for debugging purposes?

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, activity-manager

I'm currently working on an Android application and facing challenges in debugging and understanding the real-time Activity and Fragment stack. Is there a recommended approach or tool that allows me to visually inspect the activity and fragment stack at runtime? I'm particularly interested in a solution that provides real-time updates to help me identify the flow of my application and troubleshoot any unexpected behavior. Any guidance or suggestions on tools, libraries, or techniques would be greatly appreciated.

I have already attempted using ADB commands such as 'dumpsys' and explored a GitHub library called 'easy-dumpsys' to gather information about the stack.